# UIImage from imageWithCGImage doesn't retain pointer (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage, cgimageref

I have a custom class `Frame` that gets image data from multiple sources. The class can generate an `UIImage`. The problem is when a generated `UIImage` is drawn on the screen, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Callstack is empty, it ends at start->main->UIApplicationMain.

I think it has something to do with `CGImageCreate` and that the pointer isn't retained somehow. But I have a hard time figuring out why. The XCode debugger shows the `UIImage` exists right before it's added as a subview through `UIImageView`, but after it just crashes. I've also tried to draw it directly to a custom `UIView` with `drawRect`, but it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at `drawRect`.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```c
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];

// To NSData
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
CFDataRef dataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
const unsigned char *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(dataRef);
const signed long length = CFDataGetLength(dataRef);

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:pixels length:length];
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);

// NSData to UIImage
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGDataProviderRef dataProviderRef =
CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data.bytes, data.length, NULL);
CGImageRef imageRef2 =
CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, 4 * width, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo,
              dataProviderRef, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef2];

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProviderRef);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

//Show UIImage
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
imageView.image = image2;
//Breakpoint here shows that `image2` is equal to `image`
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
//EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```